# Swift3 Error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'ArraySlice<Int>' operands

Tags: arrays, swift

i'm iterating array and comparing values via indexes but getting error

[image]

Here is my code

```
class Solution {
   func threeSum(_ alice: [Int] = [5,6,7], _ bob: [Int] = [3,6,10]) {

       var aliceP = 0
       var bobP = 0

 for i in [0..<alice.count] {
           if alice[i] > bob[i] {
               aliceP += 1
           } else if alice[i] < bob[i] {
               bobP += 1
           }
       }


       print(aliceP, bobP)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `[0..<alice.count]` to just `0..<alice.count`. Without the brackets, `i` will be an index as needed, iterated over the given range. With the brackets, you create an array of with a single CountableRange so the only value of `i` is a `CountableRange<Int>` instead of the desired simple `Int`.

Comment: One last thing how i can iterate in reverse direction?

Comment: With some trivial searching you would have found `for i in (0..<alice.count).reversed() {`.